# Webpage does not load while intercepting with Burp

Tags: http, https, proxy, burp, interception

Can someone explain to me why I can not access a webpage while intercepting with BurpSuite? When turning off the interception everything works fine and I can see the traffic in the http history section. But when turning interception on, the webpages are not loading.

I therefore ask for an explanation to understand this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web page is not loading because Burp has intercepted the request and is awaiting action.

[Docs/Tutorial: Intercept HTTP Traffic with Burp Proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/getting-started/intercepting-http-traffic)

> Step 2: Intercept a request
>
> Using Burp's browser, try to visit https://portswigger.net and observe that the site doesn't load. Burp Proxy has intercepted the HTTP request that was issued by the browser before it could reach the server. You can see this intercepted request on the Proxy > Intercept tab.
>
> Viewing an intercepted request in Burp Proxy The request is held here so that you can study it, and even modify it, before forwarding it to the target server.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Proxy-settings and dont forget to had filters for intercept !

[Burp'S Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YBhm.png)

And in this setting check this cases :

[Burp's Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNwNd.png)

Comment: thanks, that helped! Also the colors are good 